# What anti-smuggling measures were implemented on the border between Ukraine and Hungary in the late 1990s and early 2000s?

Tags: europe, crime, hungary, ukraine

Closely related cross-site: [Why did Hungary joining the E.U. cause oil prices fall to be only marginally higher than they were in Ukraine?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54925/why-did-hungary-joining-the-e-u-cause-oil-prices-fall-to-be-only-marginally-hig)

Somewhat related cross-site: [Were schoolteachers really paid substantially less than $45 per month in 1990s Ukraine?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24451/were-schoolteachers-really-paid-substantially-less-than-45-per-month-in-1990s-u)

The Ukrainian novel *Carbide* by Andriy Lyubka refers to a smuggler in 1990s Ukraine who would smuggle vodka, cigarettes, and gasoline from Ukraine to Hungary. This was initially highly profitable, given that (according to the novel at least) gasoline cost 3 times as much in Hungary as it did in Ukraine in the 1990s. However, it mentioned that the price of gasoline fell considerably in Hungary after it joined the E.U., and that the Hungarian border guards had evidently wised up to the scam and started implementing measures to prevent gasoline smuggling:

> Fifteen years had trickled by since [starting the smuggling operation], and the whole fuel-smuggling scheme had lost its viability. Hungary had jointed the European Union, and the weighted cost of gas and diesel had levelled out across all Europe. Yes, there still was a slight difference in price between Ukraine and the EU, but it was barely enough to feed one marginal smuggler, at best. The customs officers had started writing down your car's mileage and gas levels at the border, so you'd get slapped with a huge fine if you went through the same checkpoint a half hour later with your gas tank nearly empty after driving just a few miles. Smugglers would cross the border, sell their gas, head to some parking lot, and sit there for five or six hours. They'd hook up a special device that looked like a meat grinder to the odometer and spin the handle. They'd crank up the mileage in just a few short minutes and then head back. The customs officer would see they'd crossed the border seven hours ago and driven over four hundred miles in that time, so yeah, obviously they were going to be running on empty. They could get around paying big fines that way, but they'd make a measly 20 bucks or so for a run that could take up to 10 hours.

I'm somewhat confused about this, though. Was this an official policy change, or just the border guards "wising up" to what was going on? Was this part of a general trend of tightening border security in the late 1990s and early 20002? If so, what other kinds of measures were implemented too? What precipitated these changes?

Comment: This is really not a history question. Simple answer: (then and now) loss of tax revenue (2007: Hungary: 0.42 euros mineral oil tax on petrol, 0.35 euros on diesel per liter). Today, customs free is the amount in the tank plus 10 liter.

Comment: The question in the title is completely different than any of the 3 questions I'm seeing in the body. Could we get that made more consistent?

Comment: @T.E.D. Does my edit help?

Comment: Not an answer, but across all of Eastern Europe, Russia, Central Asia and even China there was a notable trend from wild and turbulent (and corrupt) 1990s to much more orderly 2010s.. So what is described in your blockquote is not really surprising at all. You can see very similar trends with cigarette smuggling into Germany or vehicle smuggling in the other direction.